# HTML Table Outside border multiple TR

Tags: javascript, html, css, row, html-table

I have a html table and it haves some rows with rowspan, The simple border of the td is **1px solid black**, but I need to make a thicker border on the Row group with rowspan. Sorry for my English, I'm going to add an image to be more clear.
This is how I need to make the table:
[image]

I tryed to add

```
table tr{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

But it make thicker the rows without rowspan too.
Does somebody have a solution in CSS or JS?

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
table td, table th{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 14px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you modify your actual markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify your actual markup you can use multiple [tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) elements, and then style:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 14px;
}
table tbody {
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val</td>
      <td>val</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you can't modify your actual markup and you can use Jquery you can make it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Remove the actual tbody
  $('tr').unwrap();

  //Give the th a thead element
  $('th').first().parent('tr').wrap('<thead></thead>');

  //Evaluate wich td has rowspan and wrap on tbody based on number of rowspans
  $('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
      var numb = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"), 10),
          par = $(this).parent('tr').index('tr');
      $("tr").slice(par, par + numb).wrapAll('<tbody></tbody>')
    }
  })
})
```

**Check the Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').unwrap();
  $('th').first().parent('tr').wrap('<thead></thead>');
  $('td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("rowspan") != undefined) {
      var numb = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"), 10),
        par = $(this).parent('tr').index('tr');
      $("tr").slice(par, par + numb).wrapAll('<tbody></tbody>')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 14px;
}
table tbody {
  border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val</td>
    <td>val</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this looks very useful but the actual markup is modified from a javascript function to join the same **cells** into a single **cell** with rowspan.

Comment: @djsony90, ok so the markup you post is that after the js function ? ... can u use jquery?

Comment: I used your idea **$(this).attr("rowspan") != undefined** but simplified. https://jsfiddle.net/eduh7hsg/2/